# use the :not selector in jquery on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onchange

I have one method on, once click and once change

```
$('html').on('click', 'html:not(select, textarea)', function( event ) {

$('html').on('change', 'html:not(button)', function( event ) {
```

like :not jquery documentation say, :not(this will be excluded), but my code isn't working

do somebody has a good solution or sees the error

thats the full code block

```
$('html').on('click', 'html:not(select, textarea)', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elementId = event.target.id;

    app.callController(elementId);
});
```

thank you

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Use as `$('body').on('change', 'body:not(button)', function( event ) {

Comment: sure it wont, u'd like to listen all click events and change events on all elemns but select and textarea ?

Comment: Can you imagine a `<html>` element that is a `<button>` at the same time? :)

Comment: i had window before but don't work too, i tried about an hour yesterday so now i thought i'd better ask ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're essentially binding your handler to every element (except select and textarea), and you're handling this as a delegated event, there really isn't any need to write the more complex delegated event handler syntax; simply bind your handler directly to `'html'`, and wait for events to bubble:

```
$('html').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("select, textarea")) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    var elementId = e.target.id;
    app.callController(elementId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html:not(select, textarea)
```

If this was CSS, then that would be a syntax error. `:not()` can only hold a simple selector. jQuery allows more complex selectors there, but you still have the same problem as described for the next example:

```
html:not(button)
```

That means *An `<html>` element that is not a `<button>` element* … which is the same as `html` since no element will ever have two types at the same time.

Presumably you are actually looking for:

```
:not(select):not(textarea)
```

and

```
:not(button)
```

Comment: @JamesRichford — Argh. Mutter, mutter, jQuery non-standard selector syntax.